# Issues with $(window).width() and scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get this code to only work if the device window is bigger than 960px, and it should only trigger when the window scrolls down 700px. The later part works however the first part does not.

The code works perfectly on where it fades in and then fades out, however I do not want it to do so on mobile devices, because the scroll point (700px) is too far down and is creating issues.

```
$(function () {
    var header = $('.fadein');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (($(window).width() < 960) && (scroll >= 700)) {
            header.removeClass('.fadein').addClass('.fadeout').fadeIn();
        } else {
            header.removeClass('.fadeout').fadeOut().addClass('.fadein');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does "the first part does not" mean that the `fadein`/`fadeout` classes are toggled even when the window is <= 960px wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to split that `if` statement ?

For example (second `if` will fire only if width is at least 960px)

```
if($(window).width() >= 960) {
    if (scroll >= 700) {
        header.removeClass('.fadein').addClass('.fadeout').fadeIn();
    } else {
        header.removeClass('.fadeout').fadeOut().addClass('.fadein');
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved it! Curious why this worked over the other method?

Comment: Because that combination of your conditions ... your `if` part would execute if width is less than 960 `and` scroll is at least 700, every other combination would execute `else` part

Comment: I think it was actually just a typo: `<` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue is accidentally using `< 960` instead of `> 960`, but you might also change to checking `innerWidth` rather than `width` if you really are interested in the `window`'s width and not just the `screen`'s width.

For this demo I reduced the target values to `500` and `200` to work better in a SO snippet. (Resize your browser window and run the snippet again to see it working above and below the 500px threshold.)

```js
console.log("width: " + $(window).innerWidth() );
$(window).scroll(function () {
    const
      div = document.getElementById("div"),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( ($(window).innerWidth() > 500) && (scroll >= 200) ) {
      div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else {
      div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
});
```

```css
#div{ height: 300vh; border: 1px solid grey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: I'll have to take a deeper look at this, I appreciate providing me with an alternative way to approach this!

Comment: It's not actually that different. The only significant change is from `$(window).width()` to `$(window).innerWidth()`. You could say `innerWidth` is more dynamic -- it cares about the size of the window or frame the user is looking at. (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth). Another similar-but-different property is `clientWidth`.